# Hoar's dogma seems to indicate to value true justice above the law. Are there further details on this in other sources?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

One of Hoar's dogma (**Uphold true and fitting justice and maintain the spirit of law, not the letter of law**) seems to point to the fact that to a devotee of hoar justice is more important than law and law must not be taken literally but to be interpreted according to the alleged spirit of that law.

I would like to have more details on this but I couldn't find much on my own. Are there official sources that expand on this? Are novels considered official? I could accept quotes from those too.

I'm mostly interested to the Hoar before the spellplague (that is, I play using the Forgotten Realms Campaign 3.x edition) but any information on this will do.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "Lawful" portion of Good, Evil, and Neutral typically means that the character obeys A set of rules or laws, not necessarily the laws of the land. It just so happens for many Lawful Neutral and Lawful Good characters that their personal code coencides with the law of the kingdom.

Comment: Your question "which side do you think is right" is opinion-based. Furthermore, alignment related questions tend to attract a lot of opinion based answer. Your question is likely to have a hard time based on those grounds, so I'd kindly suggest to rephrase it. I learned the hard way on one of my questions :)

Comment: @Nyakouai how would you suggest they rephrase it? This question seems POB at its core and inherently based in the problematic concept of alignment. But if you have a way to avoid that, please do suggest that specifically.

Comment: I think the main factor would be how the character has expressed his "Lawful" beliefs previously. Has he typically shown that he upholds the people's law, or of general justice?

Comment: You might be able to get a workable question about whether or not the cleric's stance is in agreement with Hoar's dogma but the question of "would an [insert alignment here] character do X" is probably never going to work here. See [this meta topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/are-questions-about-alignment-on-topic).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose This kind of question is hard to phrase adequately for SE. Plus, the answers may well ignore a flawless phrasing and still be opinion based. As Carcer pointed, the safest way is to provide the "legal ground" upon which ruling must be issued, but it can be tricky. So, sadly, I don't see a good way to rephrase (and hence, I did not VTCed it, since it would be a bit hypocritical on my part, I think).

Comment: Consider rephrasing this question to ask about sources and what do they say about the deity, his approach to law and justice. This could be objective. https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Hoar could be helpful then. Now, there is simply no hard and fast way to know what chatter of certain alignment would or wouldn't say. Alignment is only a shortcut to a sea of life philosophies.

Comment: I asked this question knowing this might've been the question's end, but I was hoping that having 2 definite sides to choose from would be enough to avoid it being both "too broad" and "opinion based". I'll try to rephrase it entirely in a different way (i have made some edits but i reckon it's not enough)

Comment: May I suggest rephrasing this to something like *Hoar's dogma says* justice is above the law. *Do official sources provide any further explanation of this aspect this god's dogma?*

Comment: Will try, thanks. Would it be ok if i ask something like that "*Hoar's dogma says justice is above the law. Do official sources provide any further explanation of this aspect this god's dogma and how does this work for a LN character?*"

Comment: Sorry, but, on that last part — *and how does this work for a LN character* —, no; that will see the question remain on hold. Opinions on what lawful neutral means depend starkly on the individual. In fact, agreement on what *any* alignment *means* will be startlingly rare. You're better off asking that last part of the DM.

Comment: Allright i will limit the question on the dogma part, thanks

Comment: (Also, if you're going to ask *only* about Hoar's dogma, you may not care what edition of *D&D* it's from. If that's the case, consider tagging the question instead as `dungeons-and-dragons` and `lore` to broaden the sources answers can draw from.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan as far as I remember edition changes were reflected as world changes in Forgotten Realms. Hoar was loosing and gaining prttfolios, was changing his mode of operation etc. Knowing it's 3.5 helps to know what stage of Hoar we are talking about. Of course, just giving the point of FR history would work even better.

Comment: @Mołot O, sure, but answers—depending, of course, on how the asker revises the question—are supposed to focus on one aspect of Hoar's dogma not on Hoar himself. I think that if it's even possible to trace the development of that aspect through multiple editions and that dogma changes, the asker might find knowledge of such changes useful. (Then the player can say, "My faith sees me worship Hoar as he was before [cosmic event that shook the Realms… again],")

Comment: I have edited the question hoping to not be opinion based anymore this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AD&D 2e sourcebook *Powers and Pantheons* has 2-3 pages of lore about Hoar. 3e does not change that lore much, so this source could be useful for you to imagine how Hoar's faithful see the world. The following summary information is based on this sourcebook.

Hoar has two aspects. The first one is invoked by those seeking vengeance. Whenever someone guilty meets an unfortunate fate that is befitting the crime, Hoar is given credit. His more benign aspect is known in the North, where he is seen more as a god of poetic justice. Many bounty hunters and some assassins pay service to Hoar before a hunt.

This dual aspect is also reflected in his interactions with other powers. For example Beshaba is listed as an ally, as he seems to be happy to unleash bad luck on the deserving. Both Tyr and Shar try to influence him; Shar wants to turn him into a blind servant of bitter vengeance, while Tyr hopes to kindle his black humor and convert his dogma more towards poetic justice.

We note that this dogma can put vengeful justice above law. We can imagine a society which prefers laws and punishment to deter future crimes, and not necessarily to comfort the victims. In such a society, Hoar's followers could in principle go beyond laws if they deem a particular kind of punishment is actually more appropriate for a given crime. They will still need to be just, have a sense of fairness so that punishments fit the crime, but each punishment could be different depending on the offender and the way the crime was committed. (For example, let's imagine a murderer. The law might dictate capital punishment, with some "humane" means. A devotee of Hoar might want inflict pain before the punishment if the original crime was violent.)

Quoting from P&P, page 30:

> No injustice is too large or too small for revenge to be sought and a fitting punishment meted out. Actions of this type have caused most town watches and Tyrists to brand priests of the Doombringer as vigilantes and raised the stature of the priesthood to that of champion of downtrodden and underdogs in the eyes of the common folk.